# How do I set a default loadout of level 1 REQs for Warzone?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

Normally in Warzone you initially spawn with the stock assault rifle and pistol, both level 1 REQs.  As you continue to unlock new weapons from REQ packs, you will unlock additional weapons as various REQ levels, but some will be level 1 REQs.  To switch to these after spawning, you need to visit a REQ station while still alive, since you don't have access to the load out menu when the game first starts.

Is there a way to set a starting or default loadout of level 1 REQs so I don't have to visit a REQ station before my first death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great idea, unfortunately it is not possible. Currently, the only way to change your loadout is to get to a REQ station at the start of the Warzone match or when you respawn during the match.

There was a post about this on the [official forums](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/warzone-suggestion---automatic-loadout-swaps/d8d6d3a2-fa56-4374-a734-42c70c3206d8/posts). But it didn't get any traction and never materialized.